# My app crashes after Room migration that adds a column to existing table

Tags: android, android-room

My app is a simple personal target management app. It has only one model, **TargetModel**, defined like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "targets")
public class TargetModel implements Parcelable {
    // ..
    // obmitted the constants

    // Fields
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private double goal;
    private double progress;
    private int unit;
    private double defaultUpdateAmount;
    private String notes;

    // Constructors
    public TargetModel(String title, double goal, double progress, int unit, double defaultUpdateAmount, String notes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.defaultUpdateAmount = defaultUpdateAmount;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public TargetModel() {
    }
    // ...
    // obmitted getters and setters and parcelable implementation
}
```

When starts, it will get all targets in database and display them in a recycler view. So far so good.

But now I want to add a column **period** to the model, so I do the migration like this:

**1. The updated model**:

```
@Entity(tableName = "targets")
public class TargetModel implements Parcelable {
    // ..
    // obmitted the constants

    // Fields
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private double goal;
    private double progress;
    private int unit;
    private double defaultUpdateAmount;
    private String notes;
    private int period;    // 1. added new field

    // Constructors
    public TargetModel(String title, double goal, double progress, int unit, double defaultUpdateAmount, String notes, int period) {    // 2. include the field in constructor
        this.title = title;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.defaultUpdateAmount = defaultUpdateAmount;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.period = period;     // 3. also assign the period value
    }

    public TargetModel() {
    }
    // ...
    // obmitted getters and setters and parcelable implementation
}
```

*I also fix the existing code that creates new TargetModel. Just pass in a default value 0.*

**2. The migration** (I'm keeping it in a separate class):

```
public class AddPeriodToTarget {
    public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE targets ADD COLUMN period INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
        }
    };
}
```

**3. The database code**:

```
@Database(entities = TargetModel.class, version = 2)   // 1. incremented version from 1 to 2
public abstract class TargetDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static TargetDatabase instance;

    public abstract TargetDao targetDao();

    public static synchronized TargetDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), TargetDatabase.class, "targets")
                    .addMigrations(AddPeriodToTarget.MIGRATION_1_2)    // 2. added this line to include the migration
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

But now the app crashes. When I debug the app, whenever I try to get the targets and observe its result to update the recycler view, the app crashes.

```
public class ViewTargetsFragment extends Fragment {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // init properties
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        mNavController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
        // setup toolbar
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(mNavController.getGraph()).build();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)(view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_viewTargets));
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.view_targets_menu);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_viewTargets_settings:
                        mNavController.navigate(ViewTargetsFragmentDirections.actionViewTargetsToViewSettingsFragment());
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_viewTargets_add:
                        mNavController.navigate(ViewTargetsFragmentDirections.actionViewTargetsToAddTargetFragment());
                        return true;
                    case R.id.menu_viewTargets_deleteAll:
                        handleDeleteAll();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, mNavController, appBarConfiguration);

        // stuffs
        mTargetsAdapter = new TargetsAdapter(mContext, mNavController);
        initRecyclerView();
        // init view model
        mTargetViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(TargetViewModel.class);
        mTargetViewModel.getTargets().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<TargetModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<TargetModel> targets) {
                mTargetsAdapter.setTargets(targets);
            }
        });      // *after this, the app crashes*
    }

    // ..
}
```

It's the first time I'm updating existing Room database with migration. What's worse is the logcat tab in my Android Studio doesn't show the error why it crashed. Now I'm not sure what the problem is. Please help me out.

It's worth noting that if I just remove the app and its data then install the app with database version 2 then it works just fine.

Comment: if it's crashing, you should try find the cause of it, that'll be much easier to investigate instead of going over all your code